# How to remove a field from Ecto model

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I would like to remove a field from an existing Ecto model:

```
field :age, :integer
```

After reading the docs I'm not sure what's the best/simple way of doing it (remove(column))?...Can you exemplify?
I've tried:

```
def change do
    create table(:users) do
      remove :age
    end
end
```

and it's not working.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want to use [alter/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#alter/2) table instead of `create table`.

```
def change do
  alter table(:users) do
    remove :age
  end
end
```

`create/2` will raise if the table already exists.

Comment: Thank you again! Do you know how to access (as in the phoenix framework ecto models guide): "If we log in to our database server, and connect to our hello_phoenix_dev database, we should see our users table"?

Comment: This command will do it: `echo "\dt" | psql -U postgres -W -h localhost hello_phoenix_dev`

Replace postgres with your postgres user name.

Comment: Nice! And the command that translates to in the actual users table (that appears next and that shows us the contents/columns content of the table)? I'm making progresses with your help :)